# How to put Graphql queries to fetch data from Wordpress API inside react components instead of templates in GatsbyJS?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I'm working on a static website made using GatsbyJS, for which the data is hosted on Wordpress. Till now, I'm able to fetch the posts and pages data and create pages for them using templates using [this plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/?=wordpress).

My requirement is to create a gallery or carousel section using an ACF field in any post or page in any of my existing React components. But, I'm unable to wrap my head around this as there needs to be some settings done in gatsby-node.js for this, I suppose.

I created the GraphQL query to do this and it is fetching the correct data. But now the issue is that I don't know where to put this query.

Here is the GraphQL query:

```
`query MyQuery {
  wordpressPost(wordpress_id: {eq: 11}) {
    acf {
      facebook
      twitter
      image {
        localFile {
          url
        }
      }
      slider {
        image_caption
        slider_image {
          localFile {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Please let me understand this better as I'm kind of stuck in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create query in component simply use **staic query**. The example has been copy pasted from [gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/):

```js
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query HeadingQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <header>
        <h1>{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
      </header>
    )}
  />
)
```